# What's the correct exception type to NACK a message using annotation based listener in spring-boot with amqp?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using spring boot with spring-amqp and annotation based listener to consume message from a rabbitmq broker.
I've a spring component which contains a method like this:

```
  @RabbitListener(queues = "tasks")
  public void receiveMessage(@Payload Task task) {...}
```

I'm using the AUTO mode to acknowledge messages after successful execution of receiveMessage(...). If i detect a special error, i'm throwing AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException to get this message into a configured dead letter queue. Now i need to nack a message only, so that the message gets requeued into the main queue of rabbitmq and another consumer has the possibility to work on that message again.

Which exception should i throw for that? I wouldn't like to use channel.basicNack(...) like described here (http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/amqp.html) if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as `defaultRequeueRejected` is `true` (the default) in the container factory, throwing any exception other than `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` will cause the message to be rejected and requeued.

The exception must not have a `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` in its cause chain (the container traverses the causes to ensure there is no such exception).